# Dual Licensing - AFL/GPL

Tags: multi-licensing

I would like to use a library that is dual licensed:  library is licensed to you under your choice of the Academic Free License version 2.1, or the GNU General Public License version 2 (or, at your option any later version).

My understanding is that I can chose to use the library under the AFL and just by removing the GPL license text one must fulfil only the AFL license conditions.

Is this correct ? If not what are the best practices in this case ?

(I am asking about this specific case as when a library has a dual license — open source / commercial it's easier to distinguish)

Edit: License Text : https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/COPYING

Comment: Can you provide more details on the actual notice that exists in code? You are likely referring to some GNOME, but please specific.

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/COPYING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would double check there aren't parts of the code licensed under GPL and other parts licensed under the AFL. Based on the FAQ (https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-faq.html), I would say you indeed have the option to pick one of the two licenses for the entire library.

> what are the best practices in this case ?

If you want to be extra careful, I would remove references to the license that you don't want from ALL files in the dbus source. Most source files should have a copyright notice in block comment at the top of the file. An example: https://cgit.freedesktop.org/dbus/dbus/tree/bus/activation-helper.c. If you want to use the AFL license, remove the GPL stuff from this comment header.